# break string after each comma and store values in different variables using jquery

Tags: jquery

after a call to a application backend it returns me the following string .

```
authentication=1,b_number=123,fname=john
```

i want to break the string using jquery and want to store values in different variables . like

```
var fname = john
```

I made a function using jquery split to achieve this but it seems to alert the `undefined`.

```
var a ="authentication=1,b_number=123,fname=john";

var parts = a.split(",");

var table = {};

for( var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++ ) {
    var pair = parts[i].split('=');
    table[pair[0]] = pair[1];
}


var gid = table.id;

var gpic =table.pic;
```

Comment: well, for one, `id` and `pic` aren't in `a`. Otherwise, it works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/jPMcF/

Comment: To add to @KevinB's comment, your `table` object is going to contain the fields `authentication`, `b_number`, and `fname`, but not `id` or `pic`, because you assign the fields' names dynamically with `table[pair[0]]` (which uses the actual values from your string).